# How can I change the image background when button is clicked

Tags: java, android, onclick

How Can I change the image background when a button is clicked?
I want to be able to let the user press the button and it adds the movie to the database and when he presses it again it takes it out of the SQL Table and for them to be able to distinguish between if it's in the database or isn't with the displayed image.

Here is what I have so far:

```
isPressed = false;

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

final FloatingActionButton favoriteButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
        .setContentView(imageView)
        .setLayoutParams(params)
        .setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.favorite_unselected)
        .setTheme(FloatingActionButton.THEME_DARK)
        .setPosition(FloatingActionButton.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT)
        .build();

favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // If button already pressed then I want it un-favorite
        if(isPressed)
            favoriteButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_unselected);
        else
            favoriteButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_selected);

        isPressed = !isPressed;
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using `fab.setImageDrawble(...);`

Comment: Can't I forgot to add that `favoriteButton` is an ImageView 
`ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this)`

Comment: [setImageDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) is on ImageView ...

Comment: Ah sorry, I can't set an Image Drawable in the floating action button

Comment: I'm using the following https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu

Comment: Have you tried using `fab.setContentView(...)` and passing in an `ImageView` that displays the image you want to use?